# Error on discord commando A command with the name/alias "${command.name}" is already registered

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, commando

I am using Node.js Discord.js-commando, I try to run my code but this comes up please tell me if you are having the same error or have a fix. The code under is from the index.js for your help. Please reply to this message and tell me if you know ut

```
C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover Now\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\registry.js:129
                        throw new Error(`A command with the name/alias "${command.name}" is already registered.`);
                        ^

Error: A command with the name/alias "help" is already registered.
    at CommandoRegistry.registerCommand (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover Now\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\registry.js:129:10)
    at CommandoRegistry.registerCommands (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover Now\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\registry.js:176:9)
    at CommandoRegistry.registerCommandsIn (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover Now\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\registry.js:200:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover Now\index.js:67:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

This is my code/ command handler in my index.js I have 5 categories each with their own name. Please rply with a a answer if u have one

```
client.registry
  .registerDefaultTypes()
  .registerGroups([
    ["fun", "Fun Commands"],
    ["moderation", "Moderation Commands"],
    ["special", "Special Commands"],
    ["misc", "Misc Commands"],
    ["music", "Music Commands"]
  ])
  .registerDefaultGroups()
  .registerDefaultCommands()
  .registerCommandsIn(path.join(__dirname, "commands"));
```

Comment: It looks like `path.join(__dirname, "commands")` contains the command `help` that is already registered.

Comment: How can i fix this it is my first time working with commando.

Comment: Don't register `help` twice. It's once registered in `registerDefaultCommands()` and once in `registerCommandsIn(path.join(__dirname, "commands"))`. You can either disable the default command or remove your custom command.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things here, either change your custom command from `help` to something else like `commands` or disable the default command `help` provided by commando.

To disable commando's default `help` command you can do this

```js
client.registry
  .registerDefaultTypes()
  .registerGroups([
    ["fun", "Fun Commands"],
    ["moderation", "Moderation Commands"],
    ["special", "Special Commands"],
    ["misc", "Misc Commands"],
    ["music", "Music Commands"]
  ])
    .registerDefaultGroups()
    .registerDefaultCommands({
      help: false,
      prefix: true,
      ping: true,
      eval: true,
      unknownCommand: true,
      commandState: true,
    })
  .registerCommandsIn(path.join(__dirname, "commands"));
```